# fgets() repeating previous string while reading from a blank line

Tags: c

I am creating a game of life program in C, the problem is when reading from a text document in one of my functions, if there's a blank line, the input from the previous line will be repeated when it shouldn't be.

For example, given an input of

```
    x
     x
      x

   x
```

The output is giving me, as a starting generation,

```
   x
    x
     x

   x x
```

Here is the code:

```
FILE    *f;
int i, j, k;
char    s[100];
f = fopen (input, "r");
for (j=0; j<height; j++) {
    if(fgets (s, 100, f) != NULL && (s[0] != '\r' && s[0] != '\n')) 
    {
    for (i=0; i<width; i++) {
        board[i][j] = s[i] == 'x';
    }
    }
}
fclose (f);
```

Before using the if statement, the output would have been

```
x
 x
  x
  x
x x  
x x
x x
x x
x x
```

Comment: `for (i=0; i<width; i++)` That loop is wrong. You need to stop if you see a newline (`'\n'`) or NUL (`'\0'`) character.

Comment: That's what the if statement is for. The problem is, s[4] from line 3 is being retained on line 5 (due to blank line in between) and I don't know why.

Comment: @Milos, that's why you need to check whether `s[i]` is `'\n'` or `'\r'`, or `'\0'`. If so, break out of the loop.

Comment: @Milos The `if` only checks the first character. Every character needs to be checked. Hence needs to be done in the `for` loop.

Comment: Any time a subsequent line is shorter than its predecessor, you're likely to get bad results.  Note that `fgets()` does not pad the input to the length of the buffer; it only writes over what it needs to use.

Answer (score 0):

Why make blank lines a special case?

Treat them as regular input instead:

```
len = strlen(s)
for (i=0; i<len; i++) { //etc... etc... etc...
```